# How properly to throttle access to DocumentDb from WebJobs

Tags: c#, azure, system.reactive, azure-webjobs, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure WebKob with blob and queue triggers to save data to Azure DocumentDb.

From time to time I'm getting an error:

> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestRateTooLargeException: Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}

Currently I throttle requests using this code. A WebJob function:

```
public async Task ParseCategoriesFromCsv(...)
{
    double find = 2.23, add = 5.9, replace = 10.67;
    double requestCharge = Math.Round(find + Math.Max(add, replace));

    await categoryProvider.SaveCategories(requestCharge , categories);
}
```

Category provider to manipulate document db client:

```
public async Task<ResourceResponse<Document>[]> SaveCategories(double requestCharge, Category[] categories)
{
    var requestDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0 / (collectionOptions.RequestUnits / requestCharge));

    var scheduler = new IntervalTaskScheduler(requestDelay, Scheduler.Default); // Rx

    var client = new DocumentClient(endpoint, authorizationKey,
        new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = documentDbOptions.ConnectionMode,
            ConnectionProtocol = documentDbOptions.ConnectionProtocol
        });

    return await Task.WhenAll(documents.Select(async d =>
       await scheduler.ScheduleTask(
           () => client.PutDocumentToDb(collectionOptions.CollectionLink, d.SearchIndex, d))));
}
```

Task scheduler to throttle/measure/synchronize requests:

```
private readonly Subject<Action> _requests = new Subject<Action>();
private readonly IDisposable _observable;

public IntervalTaskScheduler(TimeSpan requestDelay, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    _observable = _requests.Select(i => Observable.Empty<Action>()
                                                  .Delay(requestDelay)
                                                  .StartWith(i))
                           .Concat()
                           .ObserveOn(scheduler)
                           .Subscribe(action => action());
}

public Task<T> ScheduleTask<T>(Func<Task<T>> request)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    _requests.OnNext(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            T result = await request();
            tcs.SetResult(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

So it's basically a number of constants from [`ResourceResponse<Document>.RequestCharge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn933057.aspx) but:

- When I have 1 queue triggered it works fine but when 8 queue it throws an error.
- If increase request charge in 8 times then 8 queues work fine but just 1 works 8 times slower than it could.

What a throttling/measuring/synchronization mechanism could work here well?

Comment: Your code is so very convoluted. You've got fragments of classes and you're mixing Rx with TPL. I would think that there is a simple bit of Rx code that would do exactly what you need in just a few lines of code. Can you please let us know what the core operations you are performing and what the class signatures are?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I was afraid to over-complicate my question. So actually it's at least 4 different classes, quite thin and covered by an interface wired up by a container.

Comment: You've most definitely made it over complicated. Putting in the correct structure would help us.

Comment: @Enigmativity fair enough, I'll refactor my question, thanks for the review

Comment: That's helped quite a bit. You've basically used Rx to set up a pipeline that will execute actions. It's very complicated and when I get a chance to go thru it in more detail I'll see if I can simplify for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity: would appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: I've given an answer a go. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting .NET SDK 1.8.0, we automatically handle the Request Rate too large exceptions to a reasonable extent(will retry 9 times by default and honor the retry after returned from server for next retry).

In case you need greater control, you can configure the RetryOptions on the ConnectionPolicy instance that you pass in to the DocumentClient objectand we would override the default retry policy with it.

So you no longer need to add any custom logic for handling 429 exceptions in your application code like above.

Answer (score 2):

When getting a 429 (Request rate too large) the response tells you how long to wait. There is a header x-ms-retry-after. This has a value. Wait for that time period in ms.

```
catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is DocumentClientException)
{
    DocumentClientException dce = (DocumentClientException)ex.InnerException;
    switch ((int)dce.StatusCode)
    {
        case 429:
            Thread.Sleep(dce.RetryAfter);
            break;

         default:
             Console.WriteLine("  Failed: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
             throw;
     }                    
}
```

Comment: Actually that's cool workaround. But I'd like to try to write a more precise scheduler rather than fire everything all together and then deal with db kicking back my requests and repeating them infinitely until all of them come through :)

Comment: Rather than fire them all at one time, could you dedicate one thread to pull from a queue of these, then you could use the 429 mechanism? That's how I handle it.

Comment: I'm node.js not .NET so my code might not help you but if you do node development, I've baked that approach into the npm package [documentdb-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils). You could look at the [source code for that](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils).

Comment: @Ryan: do you know why `DocumentClientException` has all ctors internal? There is no way to instantiate one thus test the code above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should be able to do this with your `SaveCategories` method to make it work nicely with Rx:

```
public IObservable<ResourceResponse<Document>[]> SaveCategories(double requestCharge, Category[] categories)
{
    var requestDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0 / (collectionOptions.RequestUnits / requestCharge));

    var client = new DocumentClient(endpoint, authorizationKey,
        new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = documentDbOptions.ConnectionMode,
            ConnectionProtocol = documentDbOptions.ConnectionProtocol
        });

    return
        Observable.Interval(requestDelay)
            .Zip(documents, (delay, doc) => doc)
            .SelectMany(doc => Observable.FromAsync(() => client.PutDocumentToDb(collectionOptions.CollectionLink, doc.SearchIndex, doc)))
            .ToArray();
}
```

This totally gets rid of your `IntervalTaskScheduler` class and ensures that you limit the request rate to one request per the `requestDelay` time span, but allows the response to take as long as needed. To `.ToArray()` call turns the `IObservable<ResourceResponse<Document>>` that returns many values into an `IObservable<ResourceResponse<Document>[]>` that returns a single array of values when the observable completes.

I couldn't test your code, so I tested a sample which I think simulates your code:

```
var r = new Random();
var a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);
var i = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var query =
    i.Zip(a, (ii, aa) => aa)
        .SelectMany(aa => Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            var x = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Thread.Sleep(r.Next(0, 5000));
            return x;
        }))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            started = x,
            ended = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
        });
```

I got this kind of result which shows that the requests were throttled:

```
 4026.2983  5259.7043 
 2030.1287  6940.2326 
 6027.0439  9664.1045 
 8027.9993 10207.0579 
10028.1762 12301.4746 
12028.3190 12711.4440 
14040.7972 17433.1964 
16040.9267 17574.5924 
18041.0529 19077.5545
```

Comment: Per my understanding `Observable.Timer()` produces just a single value after given delay.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. That should have been `Interval`. I'll fix it shortly.

Comment: How do you kick off `IObservable<T>`? Sorry, silly question, but I'm quite new to Rx.

Comment: You would call `.Subscribe(...)` on the observable.

Comment: Yeah, `Subscribe()` worked. When I try `Subscribe(onNext)` by some reason I'm getting everything in single hit. I would expect a hit per document from the initial sequence.

Comment: @abatishchev - That's what the `.ToArray()` is doing. I tried to mimic the signature you originally had. Try removing the `.ToArray()` and remove the `[]` from the return type.

Comment: Funny, familiar functions produce completely surprising results :)

Comment: @abatishchev - Why do you say that? What was surprising?

Comment: I mean `ToArray()` has its own meaning in Rx.